# Using a SUMIF and Drag down formula and change COLUMN references instead of ROWS

Tags: excel-formula

I have this forumula on Sheet1 in Cell A1:
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$F:$F,L$11,Sheet2!$L:$L)

As I drag this down to A2,A3, etc...  However I need the $L:$L to move across columns as I drag down to reference $M:$M in A2 and $N:$N in A3... etc.

Please Help!  I've tried the indirect, index, and offset and have not been able to get anything to work successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try in A1 and drag it down.

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$F:$F,L$11,OFFSET(Sheet2!$L:$L,0,row()-1))
```